# Copy and paste MessageDialog message

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I am creating a MessageDialog with some information.

```
MessageDialog.openInformation(getShell(), "Success", "Change "+getNumber()+" has been created.");
```

I am wanting to be able to copy the number in the dialog so I can paste it somewhere else. Is there a way to set the MessageDialog so I can accomplish this?

The API can be found [here](http://help.eclipse.org/juno/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.isv%2Freference%2Fapi%2Forg%2Feclipse%2Fjface%2Fdialogs%2FMessageDialog.html). I have not found anything in the API that really helps me out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, MessageDialog uses a `Label` to display the message. In order to allow C&P, you'd need a `Text` widget instead. So you have to create your own subclass of `org.eclipse.jface.dialogs.Dialog`.

You may look at the source code of `InputDialog` as an example. In order to make the text widget read-only, create it with the `SWT.READ_ONLY` style flag.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a class derived from `MessageDialog` and override the `createMessageArea` method with something like:

```
public class MessageDialogWithCopy extends MessageDialog
{
  public MessageDialogWithCopy(Shell parentShell, String dialogTitle, Image dialogTitleImage,
                           String dialogMessage, int dialogImageType, String [] dialogButtonLabels, int defaultIndex)
  {
    super(parentShell, dialogTitle, dialogTitleImage, dialogMessage, dialogImageType,
         dialogButtonLabels, defaultIndex);
  }

  @Override
  protected Control createMessageArea(final Composite composite)
  {
    Image image = getImage();
    if (image != null)
     {
       imageLabel = new Label(composite, SWT.NULL);
       image.setBackground(imageLabel.getBackground());
       imageLabel.setImage(image);

       imageLabel.setLayoutData(new GridData(SWT.CENTER, SWT.BEGINNING, false, false));
     }

    // Use Text control for message to allow copy

    if (message != null)
     {
       Text msg = new Text(composite, SWT.READ_ONLY | SWT.MULTI);

       msg.setText(message);

       GridData data = new GridData(SWT.FILL, SWT.TOP, true, false);
       data.widthHint = convertHorizontalDLUsToPixels(IDialogConstants.MINIMUM_MESSAGE_AREA_WIDTH);

       msg.setLayoutData(data);
     }

     return composite;
   }


   public static void openInformation(Shell parent, String title,  String message)
   {
     MessageDialogWithCopy dialog
        = new MessageDialogWithCopy(parent, title, null,  message, INFORMATION,
                                    new String[] {IDialogConstants.OK_LABEL}, 0);

     dialog.open();
   }
}
```

Comment: I'm a little confused on how this is supposed to work. I don't have a Composite to pass into the method. I guess I can create one. Then would i use the composite to open the information?

Comment: You create a class derived from MessageDialog and in that class override  the `createMessageArea` method.

Comment: Added more of the class

Answer (score 0):

Just use a JTextArea

and then

```
 JTextArea tA= new JTextArea("your message.");
 tA.setEditable(true);
```

then you can add the

```
MessageDialog.openInformation(getShell(), "Success", "Change "+getNumber()+" has been created.");
```

after, by changing it a little (you create the JTextArea, and then pass that to the JOptionPane as your message.)

Comment: This question is tagged with eclipse, so it's about SWT, not Swing.